# RichTextBox removes linebreaks from Email Headers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, richtextbox, email-headers

So I am trying to put together a simple add in for outlook which will read email headers. Getting the headers of the email is trivial enough and I have made a windows form with a RichTextBox in order to show the header (currently I am just pushing the full raw headers in, in the future I'd like to format them and make them a bit easier to read, highlight the more important parts etc, hence the RichTextBox).

The problem I am having is that once I set the textbox.Rtf, it loses the natural new lines which are in the headers, which makes them a mess. If I do textbox.Text, they have the linebreaks so they are much nicer to read.

I've tried a few different things in order to try and force the new lines to show (by using \line and \par for example) but it never seems to come through once I use .Rtf.

```
   Public Class showHeaders

        Public Shared Sub MyMsg(msg As String)
            Dim MsgUserForm1 As New MsgUserForm
            With MsgUserForm1
                MsgUserForm1.Text = "Email headers:"
                .RichTextBox1.Text = msg
                .RichTextBox1.Rtf = .RichTextBox1.Text
                .Show()
                Dim sSaveFolder As String = "C:\headers\"
                .RichTextBox1.SaveFile(sSaveFolder & "Headers.txt")
            End With
        End Sub

        Private Shared Function parseHeaders(inputHeader As String) As String
            inputHeader = inputHeader.Replace("\r\n", "\line")
            inputHeader = inputHeader.Replace("\n", "\line")
            inputHeader = inputHeader.Replace("Received:", "\b Received:\b0")
            inputHeader = "{\rtf1\ansi " + inputHeader + "}"
            Return inputHeader
        End Function

    End Class
```

Any help would be welcome as I don't understand why RichTextBox is behaving the way it is.

Comment: Can you share examples of how it shows the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vb.net doesn't allow you to use `\` to escape the `\r\n` or `\n` characters to to represent the respective Chr(13) and Char(10) characters

Instead you need to do this.

```
 inputHeader = inputHeader.Replace(VbNewLine, "\line")
 inputHeader = inputHeader.Replace(VbLF, "\line")
```

Alternately you can use  `Control.Chars.CrLf` and `Control.Chars.Lf`